# how to populate chart in WebApi in .net core?

Tags: c#, charts, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating .net core web Api application. i need to generate chart like bar,pie,etc using any chart library and save the chart as .jpg file.if any possible to do webapi in .netcore.

Comment: Do you need to generate the chart at the back- or front-end? Is it a compute intensive graph?

Comment: generate the chart at the backend .i doesn't need to display in UI.

Comment: Did you get the chart to be created in backend.. If so kindly add it as answer. I am currently looking for this part. Ift would be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Highcharts, which is a new Rich javascript based chart library. With the use of high charts, you can create the interactive charts as per your requirement.

**[`Highcharts with .Net`](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/extension/highcharts-net/)**

Comment: How would this be used in an asp.net api project not mvc?